# IIS6 Server compromised, pages being served which don't exist as asp files?

Tags: security, iis-6, asp.net

Started a new job recently which involves some work with an IIS server. We recently found that the server had been compromised as a few websites had pages appearing on Google Webmaster tools which appeared to be advertising products for some third party.

Anyway to cut a long story short I have been through the files numerous times and removed umpteen files which I suspected where the source of this erroneous page however after this I the pages themselves are still viewable?

Being that I have little knowledge of IIS and asp, could someone give me a run down of how its possible to have a page appear without a corresponding file.

This is an example 
http://www.gourockhighlandgames.org.uk/global.asp

I would have though that in the web root there would be a file global.asp which was the source of the problem however there is no such file but the page still loads. I have also ran Malwarebytes on the server itself which returned 0 infections.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do an `iisreset` after?

Comment: Yea, have tried clearing browser cache and recycling the application pull also

Comment: Check your ISAPI settings (and/or, if you have ASP.NET installed, the HttpHandlers section of your nearest web.config) for handlers that are handling specific files (by extension or name)...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the files did exist but where marked as System Files (sneaky hackers), hence why they weren't visible initially.

Never realised that by enabling 'show hidden files' for the particular folders wasn't enough to display system files also.

Lesson learned.